# SFSafariViewController redirect not working

Tags: ios, safari, mobile-safari, ios9

I'm trying to use `SFSafariViewController` to present a form that the user needs to fill out. On the form, there is a "back" button, which fires a url scheme which opens the app. The problem is that the `application:openURL:options:` method doesn't get called when the url scheme is fired by the web page. When I was using Safari to open the form instead of the `SFSafariViewController`, the scheme worked, and the `application:openURL:options:` method was called.

Any ideas why the scheme is not working with `SFSafariViewController` and how to fix it?

Comment: Have you ever figured out the problem?

Comment: This was a long time ago, so I don't remember exactly, but I'm almost certain that we figured out that SFSafariVieController couldn't do this, and reverted to navigating to the Safari app.

Comment: SFSafariViewController doesn't close on it's own but does call `application:openURL:options:`. You have to close it programmatically when `application:openURL:options:` is called.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, if you redirect from the Safari app, the `application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:` method will be called. If you redirect from `SFSafariViewController` you would use the `application:openURL:options:` method. Can you confirm you are using the correct method?

Comment: both methods are not called